# Proof writing of decimal expressions

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Claim: for an integer n greater than or equal to 2, the period of the decimal expression for the rational number 1/n is at most n-1

Proof: I am unsure how to provide a precise proof of this. 
 I am aware that you cannot have a remainder greater than n itself as since there are only n different remainders when you divide by n and once any remainder repeats, the whole process repeats. More precisely tho, we can say that no period will be longer than n-1. 
 I know that the algorithm for finding the decimal expansion of a rational m/n goes:

1) Divide m by n, so we get m=na1+r1 where r1 is the remainder
2) Next divide 10r1 by n, we get 10r1=na2+r2.

If we continue this way, the numbers a1,a2,... are the decimals for m/n. Then remainders are always

however, I think it wants you to show that the period is at most n−1. I am aware that given the algorithm we described above, if there was a period of length n, then the remainders above would have to visit every number between 0 and n-1. But what would happen? How do I write a precise proof

Comment: The point is that if you ever get the same remainder twice, then the process must become periodic from there on.

Comment: I think the OP is observing that there are $n$ possible remainders, not just $n-1$, so why can’t the period be $n$ (repeating all possible remainders repeatedly).

Comment: Yes it wants you to show that the period is at most n−1. So given the algorithm we described above, if there was a period of length n, then the remainders above would have to visit every number between 0 and n-1. What would happen then?
 @SteveKass

Comment: Suppose the remainders repeatedly cycled through all $n$ possibilities. One of those possible remainders is $0$, so at some point, you get $x=na_i+0$. What happens at the next step?